# Add argument/parameter to TFS Build Definition

Tags: build-definition, build-process-template

I have a single build process template that I use for a number different builds definitions. I want to be able to specify an argument/parameter that is different for each build definition. I'll use this value in one of the workflow activities defined in the template.

How do you create an argument/parameter for a build definition and pass it to the build process  template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've got it. In the build definition I just need to Refresh the Build process file and the arguments I'd set up in the template appeared at the bottom in the **Misc** section.